# Electron: Why occurs 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is no defined.'?

Tags: javascript, web, import, electron, require

I have a problem problem in my program using Electron.

First, I was typing `require()` code in 'main.js'.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, Menu, ipcMain } = require('electron')
```

Above code does not show an error from console. And I have creating another source file `func.js`.

I was typing `require()` code in `func.js`.

```
const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron')
```

But above code shows an error in the console.

So I don't know what is wrong. The ES6 script uses the `import ()` statement, but I do not really know if there was an error in `main.js`, but I do not know why other files fail.

Comment: Resolved. I made a small mistake. If you give the option like this, you get the same error as me. If you give 'webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: false}' option when creating main window, you can not use Node.js function.

Comment: If possible, you could write your comment as an answer to your own question, thus everyone can see that this is the right solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error & solved by adding the line bellow in main js file:

from:

```
 win = new BrowserWindow({

})
```

to:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you introduce a connecting JS code between html and corresponding Javascript file.